# How to migrate sbt InputTasks defined with ```<<=```?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've written an SBT plugin that has a few `InputTask`s that are defined with `<<=` and I'm having a hard time migrating them to `:=`.

For example, there is:

```
val gulp = inputKey[Unit]("Runs gulp commands")
gulp <<= FrontendInputTask(gulp, Frontend.gulp _)

object FrontendInputTask {
  def apply(
    key: InputKey[Unit],
    func: (FrontendPluginFactory, String) => Box[Unit]
  ): Def.Initialize[InputTask[Unit]] = {
    Def.inputTask {
      val args = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
      val log = streams.value.log
      StaticLoggerBinder.sbtLogger = log
      func((frontendFactory in key).value, args.mkString(" ")) match {
        case Failure(msg, Full(e), _) => throw e
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried changing this to:

```
gulp := FrontendInputTask(gulp, Frontend.gulp _).inputTaskValue
```

Which compiles, but, gives the error "No valid parser available" when run.

Any clues on what changes are necessary?

The code is in a public repo at [sbt-frontend](https://github.com/eltimn/sbt-frontend)